# Is there a projected coordinate system where x and y are from -1 to 1?

Tags: coordinate-system

Is there a relative projected coordinate system following the rules of:

1. Origin of the system is the geo-origin of the Earth (Null Island).
2. Longitudes are confined between -1 and 1 where 180° W is -1 and 180° E is 1.
3. Latitudes are also confined between -1 and 1 where 90° S is -1 and 90° N is 1.

Comment: Given that the globe is twice as wide as it is tall, I'd expect that, if there were such a thing, it would be (-2,2] in the X dimension, or [-0.5,0.5] in the Y.

Comment: @Vince I believe that's 4 times as wide as it is tall in your example.

Comment: No, I included an **or**.

Comment: I mean, you could create one, but it would look "squashed" for the reasons noted earlier

Comment: Web Mercator image is a square and doesn't look so bad. Do you mean if it already exist (It doesn't) or how to create it?

Comment: Web Mercator distorts the Y dimension infinitely at the poles; this should not be a role model for a good-looking projection (besides, the tiled space of 3857 isn't anywhere near the poles).

Comment: @Vince, I just said it is a square and doesn't look so bad. They aren't asking for a conformal projection, so I think an affine (with non-uniform scale) transformation of equirectangular projection won't look so bad, either.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I'd looked up on Equirectangular Projection, if I scale it down to the range I described, eg. x/180, y/90, will it be what I'm looking for?

Comment: @Pikachu620, yes, there are infinite possible projections to map the Earth to a square, but i think it will be the easiest one.

Comment: Another one (maybe nicer or maybe not): x = lon/180; y = sin(lat). You can play with them :-)

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca As Vince noted, the Mercator projection isn't square. It's infinite in the y direction if you want to include both +90 and -90. It's only square if you cut it off at something like +-85, which wouldn't meet the OP's conditions

Comment: @BarryCarter As answered to Vince, i just said the image of Web Mercator is square and doesn't look so bad. I'm pretty sure we can make a projection that meet the OP's conditions and doesn't look so bad, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such system, or at least it is not registered in any known database.  But you can create it.

There are infinite possible projections that meet your requirements, but the simplest seems to me to be the one that meets the equations:

- x = lat / 90; y = lon / 180

A map projected to that system might look like this:
[image: 1]

Obviously the projection is not conformal (for spheric datums it can be equidistant in the direction of meridians, with some esoteric unit of measure). The equations are very simple and you can analyze the deformations without too much effort (it seems like a lot until you do it). But for the time being I assume that the analysis of deformations is not included in your question.

---

It had occurred to me that other equations that transform the same space would be:

- x = sin(lat); y = lon / 180

The opinion of whether it is prettier or not is left to personal taste:

[image: 2]

---

Finally, and since the heavy lifting is done, let me take advantage of the property that your system is normalized to use a power:

- x = (lat / 90)^1.25; y = lon / 180

[image: 3]

It looks like an acceptable result to me, and I'm not sure that the warping is greater than that of the [equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection):

[image: 4]

---

The code for the image manipulations is at [this notebook](https://github.com/gabriel-de-luca/reproyeccion_personalizada/blob/main/reproyeccion_personalizada.ipynb).